# Pass TeamCity Build Number to Docker agent

Tags: docker, parameters, containers, teamcity, agent

I am currently trying to configure TeamCity to work with Docker agents.  It is building OK, but now have reached the stage of trying to pass the TeamCity parameters (e.g. build number) to the build script on the agent.  I understand environment variables aren't passed from the host to the container by default and am not sure the best way to go about it, so I was wondering if anyone could advise the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance